# How do I remove duplicate rows in my CSV?

Tags: ruby, csv

I have a CSV that has data like this:

```
A.A.B. Direct   http://www.aabdirect.com    348 Willis Ave  Mineola NY  11501   (800) 382-1002  no email
Abeam Consulting Inc    http://abeam.com    245 Park Ave    New York    NY  10167   (212) 372-8783  no email
Abeam Consulting Inc    http://abeam.com    245 Park Ave    New York    NY  10167   (212) 372-8783  no email
Alvarez & Marsal    http://www.alvarezandmarsal.com 600 Madison Ave New York    NY  10022   (212) 759-4433  no email
Alvarez & Marsal    http://www.alvarezandmarsal.com 600 Lexington Ave Ste 6 New York    NY  10022   (212) 759-4433  no email
```

The key thing here is that sometimes all columns in both rows match (like `Abeam Consulting Inc`), but sometimes that's not the case. Sometimes just the websites match, or the phone number or the name match.

The key thing is the website. If two values have the same website, I only want one.

How do I de-dupe this list in a non N+1 way?

Preferably with some native ruby method like `.uniq` or something of the sort.

Answer (score 2):

Just read those strings (which I"ve simplified to avoid the need for horizontal scrolling) into an array:

```
arr = [
  "A.A.B. Direct   http://www.aabdirect.com    (800) 382-1002",
  "Abeam Consulting Inc    http://abeam.com    (212) 372-8783",
  "Abeam Consulting Inc    http://abeam.com    (212) 372-8783",
  "Alvarez & Marsal    http://www.alvarezandmarsal.com (212) 759-4433",
  "Alvarez & Marsal    http://www.alvarezandmarsal.com 10022   (212) 759-4433"
]
```

and, as you suggest, use [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq), but with a block:

```
arr.uniq { |line| line[/\shttp:\S+/] }
  #=> ["A.A.B. Direct   http://www.aabdirect.com    (800) 382-1002",
  #    "Abeam Consulting Inc    http://abeam.com    (212) 372-8783",
  #    "Alvarez & Marsal    http://www.alvarezandmarsal.com (212) 759-4433"]
```

See [Array#uniq](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq). The regex `/\shttp:\S+/` reads, "match a whitespace followed by the string `"http:"`, followed by one or more characters other than whitespaces (greedily)".

Comment: This is the issue though. Notice how your `uniq`'d array, didn't remove the second `Alvarez & Marsal` entry when it should have? :| That seems to only remove identical rows -- where I need to remove any row where the website was previously seen.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully. I believe my answer is OK now, but tell me if it isn't.

Comment: There anyway to do this within the `CSV` class? For instance using CSV#foreach like Alireza suggests.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't look like a CSV file, as there are no field separators (e.g., commas, semicolons, etc.). If there were a field separator, then "yes" to your question. It would be particularly helpful if the file began with a header row (containing names of fields), as in that case we wouldn't need a regex to identify the URL.